# Can't create a folder if path contains cyrillic symbols? (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
var path = "P:/Projects/архив/fff";
function mkdir (dir) {  
        try {
            fs.mkdirSync(dir, 0755);
        } catch(e) {
            if(e.code != "EEXIST") {
                throw e;
            }
        }
};
mkdir(path);
```

It doesn't throw any exceptions, but I can't see created folder. It works fine with paths without cyrillic symbols.

Comment: I am a Linux user, but from what I remember the paths in Windows are written as "P:\Projects\архив\fff".
And the second point is that you can't create the `fff` folder if the `архив` is not yet defined. Usually you will get ENOENT: no such file or directory